# Not able to export my page containing Charts

Tags: export-to-excel

My webpage is having grid and charts inside the panel control when I export to excel using the panel id chart doesn't view

```
 Response.Clear();
 Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=AccountSummaryDashboard.xls");
 Response.Charset = "";
 Response.ContentType = "application/vnd.xls";
 //Response.ContentType = "application/pdf";
 System.IO.StringWriter stringWrite = new System.IO.StringWriter();
 System.Web.UI.HtmlTextWriter htmlWrite = new HtmlTextWriter(stringWrite);
 pnlGridData.RenderControl(htmlWrite);//Panel1
 Response.Write(stringWrite.ToString());
 Response.End();
```